# SwiftUI How to get changes of computed Property of NSManagedObject subclass

Tags: ios, core-data, swiftui

I am using a `List` to display a CoreData one-to-many relationship models. The list displayed the computed property. When the NSManagedObject was changed, the computed property doesn't know about it.

Let's say `People` has many `Book`s. Like the code below:

`People+CoreDataProperties.swift`

```
  extension People {
    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Contract> {
        return NSFetchRequest<People>(entityName: "People")
    }

    @NSManaged public var peopleID: String?
    @NSManaged public var name: String?
    @NSManaged public var books: Set<Book>?
    @NSManaged public var bookOrders: [String]

   }
```

The `bookOrders` is the ordered id of the books.

`BookListView.swift`

```
struct BookListView: View {
   @state var people: People //this is from @FetchRequest
   
   List {
       ForEach(people.sortedBooks.indices, id:\.self) { index in
            BookRowView(bookListItem: viewModel.books[index])
       }
   }
    
}
```

Here is the extension of People:

```
extension People {
    var sortedBooks: [Book] {
    
    
    let contractMapping = books.reduce(into: [String: Book]()) { (result, book) in
        result[book.bookID] = book
    }
    return bookOrders.map {
        contractMapping[$0]
    }.compactMap { $0 }

}
```

So when I reorder the books, which say update the `bookOrders` or there's a background request update of adding the new books then how can I notify `BookListView` update the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the BookListView declare your People as `ObservedObject`

```
struct BookListView: View {
   @ObservedObject var people: People // << now View updates for any changes here
```